# Search queries in neo4j: how to sort results in neo4j in START query with internal TFIDF / levenshtein or other algorithms?

Tags: neo4j, lucene, full-text-search, cypher, fulltext-index

I am working on a model using wikipedia topics' names for my experiments in full-text index.

I set up and index on 'topic' (legacy), and do a full text search for : `'united states'`:

```
start n=node:topic('name:(united states)') return n
```

The first results are not relevant at all:

```
'List of United States National Historic Landmarks in United States commonwealths and territories, associated states, and foreign states'
```

[...]

and the actual 'united states' is buried deep down the list.

As such, it raises the **problem**  that, in order to find the best match (e.g. levershtein, bi-gram, and so on algorithms) on results, you first must fetch *all the items* matching the pattern.

That would be a serious constraint, cause just in this case I have 21K rows, ~4 seconds.

**Which algorithms does neo4j use to order the results of a full-text search (START)?**
Which rationale does it use to sort result and how to change it using cypher?
In the doc is written to use JAVA api to apply sort() - it would be very useful to have a tutorial for appointing to which files to modify and also to know which ranking rationale is used before any tweak.

EDITED based on comments below - pagination of results is possible as: 
    n=node:topic('name:(united states)') return n skip 10 limit 50;

(skip before limit) but I need to ensure first results are meaningful *before* pagination.

Comment: Your order of skip and limit is wrong, it's : `skip 10 limit 10`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which order algorithms does lucene use to order the results. 
However, about the pagination, if you change the order of limit and skip like follows, should be ok.

`start n=node:topic('name:(united states)') return n skip 10 limit 50 ;`

I would also add that if you are performing full-text search maybe a solution like solr is more appropriate.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that an alternative solution for full-text search may be more appropriate. Legacy indexing is not recommended in Neo4j v2+. Another option would be elasticsearch.

Comment: Neo4j is promoted as full-text index capable: there must be a criteria to fetch meaningful results against a query. @ceej legacy indexing is the only way for full-text indexing in neo: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/31772256/305883] . [https://github.com/sksamuel/elasticsearch-river-neo4j] is now unsupported by ES. A post on lucene here [http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2014/10/deep-dive-on-fulltext-indexing-with-neo4j/], official page on ES here [http://neo4j.com/developer/elastic-search/]. I have no Java skill: i would like (and need :) to use only cypher / python, and possibly only native neo4j.

Comment: @user305883 - the method described is documented by Neo4j as **legacy** indexing. In the manual it states "As of Neo4j 2.0, this is not the favored method of indexing data in Neo4j, instead we recommend defining indexes in the database schema.". You're right - you can do it. But just because you can does not mean that you should.  Elasticsearch has a REST API that you can use to interact with it, indexing, searching and gives you a whole bunch more functionality. It is tuned for full text search. Neo4j is not. I was merely echoing the sentiment about thinking carefully about what you need.

Comment: @ceej :) nothing personal here: I quote the comment given by Neo4j guys in previous answer I posted: "Full text is only available in manual / auto indexing" (legacy). **Which criteria is natively used to sort results for a best match against a keyword?**

I look for native / cypher or python solutions to interact with the db. Since I am also extending the `start` query with a traversal + pagination, it will be simpler if native. 

However, if you are familiar with ES and could appoint a tutorial / demo to set up ES + neo in python, or give some hint on chat, I do appreciate!!

Comment: I want to add another comment: in lucene documentation about Fuzzy search (levenshtein):
[http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html]
 - See also post: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/25557613/305883].

Results between
 `start n=node:topic('name:(dna)') return n limit 5 skip 0`
 `start n=node:topic('name:"dna"~0.1') return n limit 5 skip 0`
 `start n=node:topic('name:"dna"~10') return n limit 5 skip 0`

are equivalent, no difference. (First result "DNA on DNA").
**Is there a way to expose lucene levenshtein value for debugging and see if full-text is working properly?**

Comment: Fuzzy search is expensive even in lucene. that's why most people revert to a auto-complete with prefix-search.

Comment: @MichaelHunger how items are sorted and/or hit in a `start n=node:topic('name:(united states)') return n limit 5 skip 0 ` query? First result **is not**  `united states ` (see above) and not clear which value of levenshtein (default, right?) is given. Any way to access / manipulate the order in cypher / other solution with no additional plugins to neo4j, to get coherent results and pagination, without the need to retrieve all results ahead and **then** apply a ranking algorithm?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497068/lucene-in-neo4j-has-some-misbehaviours-in-terms-of-reliable-search-querys-comp] sheds light that there is no sorting of results based on frequency of words, but based by id - now I understand why the results were odd.

Is there any doc for implementing a sort in python? or which files to modify to use the java api as `index.query(new QueryContext(query).sort(Sort.RELEVANCE));` ? (see the answer at the post I linked)

Answer (score 0):

For just a lucene index lookup with scoring you might be better off with this:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-indexes.html#rest-api-find-node-by-query

Comment: I try: `start n=node:topic('name:(dna)') return n skip 0 limit 5`, `start n=node:topic('name:"dna"~0.1') return n skip 0 limit 5`, `start n=node:topic('name:"dna"~10') return n skip 0 limit 5`: all same results, further from "DNA". `start n=node:topic('name:"united"~0.1 AND "states"~0.9') return n skip 0 limit 5` returns no results in console; `start n=node:topic('name:"united states"') return n skip 0 limit 5` returns as first results items that are clearly not ordered by levenshtein (or other ranking?): strings much longer than and distant from expected "united states".